# Android app occasionally crashing with unhelpful error message

Tags: java, android

Every so often my Android app crashes on start-up, and gives the following exception:

```
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resolveTextAlignment(ViewGroup.java:5318)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.View.resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded(View.java:11591)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded(ViewGroup.java:5262)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded(ViewGroup.java:5267)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded(ViewGroup.java:5267)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded(ViewGroup.java:5267)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.View.setLayoutDirection(View.java:5901)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1190)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-31 01:36:26.989: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It doesn't seem to reference my code in the exception, which makes it quite difficult to debug. I'm new to Android development (but fairly experienced with iOS development). Any ideas what this exception means and how I can fix it? It does only occur sometimes on startup.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to user debugger and breakpoints. It will help you find the cause of null pointer Exception.

Comment: Any chance you're updating the UI on a background thread or something? Though I think that would produce a different error. I agree with Shobhit, it's time to trace through your Activity launch.

Comment: powerj1984: D'oh, yeah you're right. On a background thread I was calling a method which updated the UI at the bottom of it (forgot about that). Thanks for your help guys, you rock.

Comment: Hi Jake, this still shows up as unanswered. You might want to make your resolution comment above into an answer. That way others will not attempt to analyze your backtrace before they find it answered in the fine print. Glad you got this fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

powerj1984: D'oh, yeah you're right. On a background thread I was calling a method which updated the UI at the bottom of it (forgot about that). Thanks for your help guys, you rock.

Comment: Which bit of UI were you modifying? Can you remember? What sort of View?

Comment: I may have been receiving this error by calling "setNumColumns" on a `GridView`